# What would the waitress normally ask if I visit a Gusto or similar restaurant?

Tags: word-choice, words

When I go to these restaurants I am never quite sure what they are asking. I think I can hear "nan nin desu ka" and then something else but not sure what that is.

Could someone help by suggesting what they might normally say and also how I could answer that if there are two of us and I would like a non-smoking table.

Comment: 何名様ですか (nan mei sama desu ka) = How many people?

二人です (futari desu) = 2 people

Comment: How about the "do you want a smoking section"?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally they say おタバコお吸いになられますか？(Otabako osuini nararemasuka?) = do you want a smoking section?

You can answer as follows.

- 禁煙で(Kin-en de) = for non-smoking
- 喫煙で(Kitsu-en de) = for smoking